# cellForRowAtIndexPath and filtering data

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview

I've got a xml file that I parse and in that xml file I need to show on screen only some precise data and display it once because there can be multiple declarations of the data in the xml. The rest of the xml data has to remain in variables for later use. I need to filter the data in the NSMutableArrays, returned by NSXMLParser, in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. But I've got white cells in my display. How do I get rid of the white cells knowing that I can't return nil from cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Here is my code (I J K L M are C type integers in my .h) :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0]];
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    lbl1.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"type"];
    NSLog(lbl1.text);
    if ([lbl1.text isEqualToString:@"MEASURES"] == YES && i == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        i = 1;
        [lbl1 release];
        return cell;
    }else if ([lbl1.text isEqualToString:@"CAPTURES"] == YES && j == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        j = 1;
        [lbl1 release];
        return cell;
    }else if ([lbl1.text isEqualToString:@"PDFREPORT"] == YES && k == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        k = 1;
        return cell;
    }else if ([lbl1.text isEqualToString:@"VIDEO"] == YES && l == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        l = 1;
        [lbl1 release];
        return cell;
    }else if ([lbl1.text isEqualToString:@"SIZINGSHEET"] == YES && l == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        m = 1;
        [lbl1 release];
        return cell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

How I get my NSMutableArray :

important variables :

```
NSMutableArray * stories; 
NSString * currentElement;
NSMutableString * currentData_id, * currentSizing_id, * currentType, * currentName, * currentSize;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentData_id = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSizing_id = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSize = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentType = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
        [item setObject:currentData_id forKey:@"data_id"];
        [item setObject:currentSizing_id forKey:@"sizing_id"];
        [item setObject:currentName forKey:@"name"];
        [item setObject:currentSize forKey:@"size"];
        [item setObject:currentType forKey:@"type"];
        HERE I FILL IT, I THINK-->>>[stories addObject:[item copy]];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"found characters in found characters: %@", string);

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"data_id"]) {
        [currentData_id appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"sizing_id"]) {
        [currentSizing_id appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        [currentName appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"size"]) {
        [currentSize appendString:string];
    }else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"type"]) {
        [currentType appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"all done!");
    NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
    [newsTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Are you returning the correct number of rows based on your conditions ? i.e. number information you want to display

Comment: Yes i'am returning the good number of rows, the thing is when this method gets called and did'n match any of my if it needs a return, in this case i have no choice to return cell, but how to make it understand i don't want to display it ?

Comment: That's what I am saying the you should use logic you are keeping in side cellForRowAtIndex for returning cell for returning an actual number of rows you required. i.e. place those conditions in numberOfRowsAtIndex and return actual rows required.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand everything :O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you populate your `stories` object by parsing the XML file, but how do you decide what elements need a cell in your tableView ?

By working with two arrays, one with the total result of your parsing and one with only the elements that need a cell you will be able to avoid blank cells.

In the right order :

```
- Create your stories array by parsing the XML
- Create you 2nd array printableStories by reducing the first array the way you want
- Edit your numberOfRowsInSection method ( = [printableStories count])
- Edit your cellForRowAtIndexPath method (just replace stories with printableStories)
```

EDIT

To populate your tableView the way you want create your 2nd array this way :

```
NSMutableArray *yourSecondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:stories];
for (NSDictionary *dico in yourSecondArray)
{
    // Here is your condition to NOT give the element a cell
    if ([dico objectForKey@"something"] == nil)
        [array removeObject:dico];
}
```

Comment: Okay i will try out your method shinyuX.

Comment: can you give me please a pointer on how to erase duplicates in a array please i tryed NSSet but nothing happend same problem have duplicates or blanks :$. I'm new to objective c so i don't know yet how to play with arrays very good, if you please can help me :).

Comment: NSXMLParser did it for me, i just declared a NSMutableArray *stories in my .h and then put [stories addObject:[item copy ]]; i will edit my question for this part to show more how it goes :).

Comment: Ok so you have an array of NSDictionnaries. What you want is to reduce it to a smaller array containing only the elements you want to give a cell to.

Comment: ^^ but how to extract the data from the array of NSDictionaries ? at least is it possible to know if NSString *X exists in the array of NSDictionaries, i think it would be simple.

Comment: Just do something like that after you parsing :

    `NSMutableArray *yourSecondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:stories];
    for (NSDictionary *dico in yourSecondArray)
    {
        // Here is your condition to NOT give the element a cell
        if ([dico objectForKey@"something"] == nil)
            [array removeObject:dico];
    }`

Comment: (Sorry for this presentation)

Comment: Thank You a lot, i will try it out and tell you if i managed to make it work :D.

Comment: Great It worked Great ! Thanks a lot ! Edit an answer please so i can rate you the good answer :).